# Missing required error components, refreshing... Next.JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Every time, after a pull, i run.

git init
git pull
npm i or npm install

In the first time all pages working as i wish. But when changing from one page to another in localhost - i have this error: missing required error components, refreshing...

In my console, i have something like that:

```
 ⨯ Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/jonasoliveira/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Pro de Jonas/next/sala-two/.next/server/pages/api/external/news-api.js'
    at Object.readFileUtf8 (/Users/jonasoliveira/.vscode/extensions/wallabyjs.console-ninja-1.0.266/out/buildHook/index.js:1144:66509)
    at Object.readFileUtf8 (node:internal/fs/sync:25:18)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:441:19)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1258:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at mod.require (/Users/jonasoliveira/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Pro de Jonas/next/sala-two/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at NodeModuleLoader.load (/Users/jonasoliveira/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Pro de Jonas/next/sala-two/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/module-loader/node-module-loader.js:15:84)
    at RouteModuleLoader.load (/Users/jonasoliveira/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Pro de Jonas/next/sala-two/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/helpers/module-loader/route-module-loader.js:14:37)
    at DevServer.runApi (/Users/jonasoliveira/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Pro de Jonas/next/sala-two/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:543:67)
    at DevServer.handleApiRequest (/Users/jonasoliveira/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Pro de Jonas/next/sala-two/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:725:21)
    at NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/Users/jonasoliveira/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Pro de Jonas/next/sala-two/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:263:48)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/Users/jonasoliveira/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Pro de Jonas/next/sala-two/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:798:17) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/Users/jonasoliveira/Documents/Documentos - MacBook Pro de Jonas/next/sala-two/.next/server/pages/api/external/news-api.js'
}
```

The page is not missing, the error does not represent reality, and missing page changes every time that i have this issue.

I don't know what to do anymore

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Maybe it has something to do with monorepo or pwa?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I just upgraded to NextJS 14.1 and I started getting this error.

If you have 'output' and 'distDir' in your next.config.js you will get this error on the dev server

```
{
  output: 'export',
  distDir: 'build',
}
```

Removing the distDir will solve this issue

I reported this
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/61905

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it happened bc I removed '.next' folder while running the dev server (npm run dev). I restarted the dev server it regenerated '.next' and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this happens but if I delete my node module and do `npm install` it works again.

Comment: This is not an answer.